# Regex return line if it contains all letters and only 2 upper case in the whole string

Tags: java, regex

I am calling a function to determine if the input string only contains **2 words all made up of only letters**. That works fine. So 'suite 123' would fail and 'maddie girl' will pass. However, I need to make sure that consecutive uppercase letters will not pass such as 'AAA Bird' I only want to allow **two uppercase** in that whole string. 
Below is what I have at the moment. Any advise would be appreciated. I am very new to regex.

```
else if (line.matches("\\s*[A-Za-z]+\\s+[A-Za-z]+\\s*"))
        {
            getName();
        }
```

Comment: So consecutive uppercase does not pass, and uppercase ≤ 2 passes. What about 2 consecutive uppercase?

Comment: 2 consecutive would be fine. I just only need 2 uppercase only in the string no matter the placement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
^(?!(.*[A-Z]){3,})[a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+$
```

It uses a negative lookahead to ensure that there are no more than 2 uppercase characters in the string, and then matches on a sequence of letters, followed by a space, followed by another sequence of letters.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Uz0B7C/1)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this regex for unicode letters:

```
^(?!(?:.*\p{Lu}){3,})\p{L}+\p{Zs}\p{L}+$
```